# Convert from single way selection to multi way selection

Tags: java, max, bluej

I need convert from single way selection to multi way selection, but i know using switch statements i cant have something like a>=b, so how do i do it?

```
if(num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3 && num1 >= num4)
   largestnum=num1;

if(num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3 && num2 >= num4)
   largestnum=num2;

if(num3 >= num1 && num3 >= num2 && num3 >= num4)
   largestnum=num3;

if(num4 >= num1 && num4 >= num3 && num4 >= num2)
   largestnum=num4;
```

Comment: thats the thing, i only searched using google, and multiway is by using the switch statement...this is a question i got from a lecturer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the multiway `if-else` statement:

```
if(num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3 && num1 >= num4) {
    largestnum = num1;
} else if(num2 >= num3 && num2 >= num4) {
    largestnum = num2;
} else if(num3 >= num4) {
    largestnum = num3;
} else {
    largestnum = num4;
}
```

Notice that every `if` has 1 less condition to check in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java's `Stream` with max method:

```
largestnum = Stream.of(..).max();
```